AWS Glue Notebook session does not read new files from S3, if a read operation was performed before new files had arrived
I am using AWS Glue Notebook, to download excel files from a site and save to s3 folder.
Here are steps carried out in one session:

I use boto3.client("s3").list_objects_v2() to get a list of files' names already saved in "s3 folder". It lists 10 files there.
I use pd.read_excel() to read a random file among these 10 files in "s3 folder".
I use boto3.client("s3").put_object() to put 4 new files to "s3 folder".
I use boto3.client("s3").list_objects_v2() to get a list of files' names saved at the moment in "s3 folder". It lists 14 files there (10 + 4).
I use pd.read_excel() to read each file among new 4 files saved in "s3 folder".
And, it throws an error: 'No such file found: "name of one of the 4 new excel files saved".'

If I skip step #2, then step #5 does not throw an error.
So, I assume, when I perform a 'read' operation on "s3 folder" in step #2 (at the time it had 10 files only), it somehow 'freezes' the 'readable' excel files list (even though, 'list' operation shows 14 files there in step #4).
Could someone please explain, why I cannot read the 4 new files, when I can actually see them there?

Did you manage to solve this issue? If I were you I would split the script in 2 jobs.
